# Discord.js Missing API PERMISSIONS [Preventing the node process from being terminated]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have made an AFK command using Change Nickname. Whenever a user above the bot's role uses this command. I get the following error(node:169)

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:169) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:169) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:169) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:169) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

This later terminates the bots process. This further terminates the bots process. Is there any way to stop the node process from being terminated without increasing the role of the bot.
Here is my code for that command

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes('start-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname(`AFK | ${message.author.username}`);
    }
    if (message.content.includes('end-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname('');
    }
});
```

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord won't allow users/bot accounts to change someone's nickname if their role is higher than your bot's.

All you can do is catch the error and send an error message to the channel.

```js
message.member.setNickname("Nickname").catch(error => message.channel.send("Couldn't update your nickname."));
```